# Search bar in TableView Controller is too short

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a tableview controller and I've added a search bar programatically.  It shows up when I scroll up in the tableview and I can see the preview text if I keep pulling on the table.
However, when I let go - the table scrolls up a few pixels and I end up with a search bar that is too short for the preview text and looks like the below. It is missing the placeholder text and it is shorter than it should be.  Help!

[image: picture 1]

If I tap in the field, it expands and shifts up to this:

[image: picture 2]

And if I then hit cancel, then it goes to how I expect it to look in the first step. But the only way I can it to this 'correct' state is to tap into the squished field with no placeholder text, then it expands, then I hit cancel and have what I want until I scroll again....

[image: picture 3]

But as soon as I scroll at all, it reverts back to this squished state in the first image.

I'm adding it programmatically in viewDidLoad() with:

```
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
search.searchResultsUpdater = self
search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
search.searchBar.placeholder = "Type something here to search"
navigationItem.searchController = search
```

Suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was unrelated to the search bar, but some legacy code that was in the controller that was there to scroll section headers with the table rather than locking them when they hit the top of the view.

Removed that and changed the table style to grouped and that fixed the header scroll while also addressing the unintended impact to my search bar.

Now all behaving as it should.  Leaving here in case useful to others.